# k3sup join success but node not joined, tls issue?

Tags: k3s

I'm quite new to kubernetes. Running on RPi4, with k3s/k3sup as it seems to be the most viable solution for arm cards. Host OS is Raspberry Pi OS 32 bits LITE, fresh install. I have a master (2Go Ram) and 2 slaves/workers (with 8Go).

Not really sure what I've done differently (I did quite a few trial and errors), but I've ended with one working slave and one not recognized.

Here is my installation script (run on master):

```
sudo apt install dnsutils -y

curl -ssL https://get.k3sup.dev | sudo sh
curl -sSL https://dl.get-arkade.dev | sudo sh # not used yet

export KUBECONFIG=`pwd`/kubeconfig

# configure ssh between master and slaves
ssh-keygen -t rsa

ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub pi@master.home
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub pi@slave1.home
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub pi@slave2.home

# install k3s / k3sup everywhere
k3sup install --ip $(dig +short master.home) --user $(whoami)
k3sup install --ip $(dig +short slave1.home) --user $(whoami)
k3sup install --ip $(dig +short slave2.home) --user $(whoami)

# slaves join the cluster, labeled as workers
k3sup join --ip $(dig +short slave1.home) --server-ip $(dig +short master.home) --user $(whoami)
sudo kubectl label node slave1 node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=worker

k3sup join --ip $(dig +short slave2.home) --server-ip $(dig +short master.home) --user $(whoami)
sudo kubectl label node slave2 node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=worker
```

k3sup join are producing output like this:

```
pi@master:~ $ k3sup join --ip $(dig +short slave1.home) --server-ip $(dig +short master.home) --user $(whoami)
Running: k3sup join
Server IP: 192.168.1.9
Enter passphrase for '/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa':
xxxxx....::server:yyyyy
Enter passphrase for '/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa':
[INFO]  Finding release for channel v1.18
[INFO]  Using v1.18.10+k3s1 as release
[INFO]  Downloading hash https://github.com/rancher/k3s/releases/download/v1.18.10+k3s1/sha256sum-arm.txt
[INFO]  Downloading binary https://github.com/rancher/k3s/releases/download/v1.18.10+k3s1/k3s-armhf
[INFO]  Verifying binary download
[INFO]  Installing k3s to /usr/local/bin/k3s
[INFO]  Creating /usr/local/bin/kubectl symlink to k3s
[INFO]  Creating /usr/local/bin/crictl symlink to k3s
[INFO]  Creating /usr/local/bin/ctr symlink to k3s
[INFO]  Creating killall script /usr/local/bin/k3s-killall.sh
[INFO]  Creating uninstall script /usr/local/bin/k3s-agent-uninstall.sh
[INFO]  env: Creating environment file /etc/systemd/system/k3s-agent.service.env
[INFO]  systemd: Creating service file /etc/systemd/system/k3s-agent.service
[INFO]  systemd: Enabling k3s-agent unit
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/k3s-agent.service → /etc/systemd/system/k3s-agent.service.
[INFO]  systemd: Starting k3s-agent
Logs: Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/k3s-agent.service → /etc/systemd/system/k3s-agent.service.
Output: [INFO]  Finding release for channel v1.18
[INFO]  Using v1.18.10+k3s1 as release
[INFO]  Downloading hash https://github.com/rancher/k3s/releases/download/v1.18.10+k3s1/sha256sum-arm.txt
[INFO]  Downloading binary https://github.com/rancher/k3s/releases/download/v1.18.10+k3s1/k3s-armhf
[INFO]  Verifying binary download
[INFO]  Installing k3s to /usr/local/bin/k3s
[INFO]  Creating /usr/local/bin/kubectl symlink to k3s
[INFO]  Creating /usr/local/bin/crictl symlink to k3s
[INFO]  Creating /usr/local/bin/ctr symlink to k3s
[INFO]  Creating killall script /usr/local/bin/k3s-killall.sh
[INFO]  Creating uninstall script /usr/local/bin/k3s-agent-uninstall.sh
[INFO]  env: Creating environment file /etc/systemd/system/k3s-agent.service.env
[INFO]  systemd: Creating service file /etc/systemd/system/k3s-agent.service
[INFO]  systemd: Enabling k3s-agent unit
[INFO]  systemd: Starting k3s-agent
```

So far so good, isn't it ? Well....

```
pi@master:~ $ sudo kubectl get node -o wide
NAME              STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION         INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                         KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
master   Ready    master   7h9m    v1.18.10+k3s1   192.168.1.9   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   5.4.51-v7l+      containerd://1.3.3-k3s2
slave2   Ready    worker   6h46m   v1.18.10+k3s1   192.168.1.6   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   5.4.65-v7l+      containerd://1.3.3-k3s2
```

Where is slave1 ???

journalctl -xeu k3s:

```
oct 22 17:20:10 master k3s[538]: I1022 17:20:10.692778     538 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.1.5:56432: remote error: tls: bad certificate
[....]
oct 22 17:20:12 master k3s[538]: time="2020-10-22T17:20:12.197507915+02:00" level=info msg="Handling backend connection request [slave1]"
oct 22 17:20:12 master k3s[538]: I1022 17:20:12.731568     538 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.1.5:56522: EOF
[....]
oct 22 17:20:12 master k3s[538]: time="2020-10-22T17:20:12.733176514+02:00" level=info msg="error in remotedialer server [400]: websocket: close 1006 (abnormal closure): unexpected EOF"
oct 22 17:22:31 master k3s[538]: E1022 17:22:31.380781     538 machine.go:331] failed to get cache information for node 0: open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache: no such file or directory
[....]
oct 22 18:22:31 master k3s[538]: I1022 18:22:31.904927     538 trace.go:116] Trace[69126570]: "GuaranteedUpdate etcd3" type:*core.Endpoints (started: 2020-10-22 18:22:31.3753156 +0200 CEST m=+20417.996929673) (total time: 529.51
oct 22 18:22:31 master k3s[538]: Trace[69126570]: [529.405364ms] [527.360568ms] Transaction committed
oct 22 18:22:31 master k3s[538]: I1022 18:22:31.905446     538 trace.go:116] Trace[2049611301]: "Update" url:/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/rancher.io-local-path,user-agent:local-path-provisioner/v0.0.0 (linux/arm) kub
oct 22 18:22:31 master k3s[538]: Trace[2049611301]: [530.448956ms] [529.964521ms] Object stored in database
oct 22 18:27:31 master k3s[538]: E1022 18:27:31.339315     538 machine.go:331] failed to get cache information for node 0: open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache: no such file or directory
[....]
oct 22 19:17:41 master k3s[538]: I1022 19:17:41.164977     538 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.1.231:56800: write tcp 192.168.1.9:6443->192.168.1.231:56800: write: connection reset by peer
oct 22 19:17:41 master k3s[538]: I1022 19:17:41.165105     538 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.1.231:56802: read tcp 192.168.1.9:6443->192.168.1.231:56802: read: connection reset by peer
oct 22 19:17:41 master k3s[538]: I1022 19:17:41.165278     538 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.1.231:56801: read tcp 192.168.1.9:6443->192.168.1.231:56801: read: connection reset by peer
oct 22 19:17:41 master k3s[538]: I1022 19:17:41.165601     538 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.1.231:56783: read tcp 192.168.1.9:6443->192.168.1.231:56783: read: connection reset by peer
oct 22 19:17:41 master k3s[538]: I1022 19:17:41.170027     538 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.1.231:56789: write tcp 192.168.1.9:6443->192.168.1.231:56789: write: connection reset by peer
oct 22 19:17:41 master k3s[538]: I1022 19:17:41.170179     538 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.1.231:56799: write tcp 192.168.1.9:6443->192.168.1.231:56799: write: connection reset by peer
oct 22 19:22:31 master k3s[538]: E1022 19:22:31.358419     538 machine.go:331] failed to get cache information for node 0: open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache: no such file or directory
[....]

etc...
```

Ok Houston we have a problem... TLS errors, with slave1. Why? And what to do ?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, started from scratch again (fresh os install everywhere), and using k3s instead of k3sup, I was able to have my nodes up and running in a mater of minutes:

```
pi@master:~ $ sudo cat /var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/node-token
xxx::server:yyy

pi@slave1:~ $ curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_URL=https://master.home:6443 K3S_TOKEN=xxx::server:yyy sh -
pi@slave2:~ $ curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_URL=https://master.home:6443 K3S_TOKEN=xxx::server:yyy sh -
```

```
pi@master:~ $ sudo kubectl get node -o wide
NAME              STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION        INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                         KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
master   Ready    master   57m     v1.18.9+k3s1   192.168.1.5   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   5.4.51-v7l+      containerd://1.3.3-k3s2
slave1   Ready    worker   9m15s   v1.18.9+k3s1   192.168.1.6   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   5.4.72-v7l+      containerd://1.3.3-k3s2
slave2   Ready    worker   9m43s   v1.18.9+k3s1   192.168.1.7   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   5.4.72-v7l+      containerd://1.3.3-k3s2
```

Great success :-)

As a reminder, please note that adding "cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory" to /boot/cmdline.txt is required on all nodes (can not remind if I did it correctly everywhere on my former installation, but with the current one, I missed it on a node and the symptoms were the same)